# plm vs lmer - differences in outputs?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

I am looking to run a random-effects model to look at attainment of pupils who are nested within schools. The model specification includes pupil-level characteristics, school-level characteristics and a school-level intercept which I have modelled as a random effect.

I was initially using lme4, with the following specification:

```
lmer(Attainment ~ pupil_chars + school_chars + (1|school_id), data=Mydata)
```

However, a Durbin-Watson test revealed there to be serial correlation in the errors from this specification, and so I am looking to estimate Newey-West standard errors for hypothesis testing.

I have found out this can be done if I use plm for the initial regression, and so now I am running the following:

```
Attainment_results <- plm(Attainment ~ pupil_chars + school_chars, index="school_id", model="random")

coeftest(Attainment_results,vcov.=vcovNW(Attainment_results))
```

This all works fine, BUT I have noticed that the estimated coefficients differ between the lmer and plm specifications, which I don't fully understand.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on why this might be the case, or alternatively any other approach I could use to deal with this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add more details? Like, how do they differ specifically? Maybe you should add example executable code.

Comment: Look at the vignette of the package `plm` which gives a little background about the differences.